# Selenium weird behaviour on second iteration

Tags: java, selenium, debugging, input, click

So guys, I have written a bunch of code(java) for automation of test input:

```
int p = Integer.parseInt((((FirefoxDriver) driver).findElementByClassName("grade").getText()).substring(14,15));
                        for (int b = 1; b <= p; b++) {
                            ((FirefoxDriver) driver).findElementByXPath("//select[" + b + "]").click();
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            ((FirefoxDriver) driver).findElementByXPath("//select[" + b + "]/option[@value='"+b+"']").click();}
```

Basically I have a bunch of dropdown inputs and I want to click on them, so that the options are made visible and then click on one of the options, and then do this on every one of the inputs in the page. For some reason though, it only works on the first iteration, on the second iteration Selenium gives me error that it can't find the tag select[2] in the html. 
here's a screenshot of the html:
[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nfonv.png)

If anyone else comes across this kind of issue, I didn't solve the problem, but I've managed to get around it. If you're trying to automate drop-down inputs, just use the xpath of the tag before the 'select' one.

Comment: Try adding implicit wait or fluent wait. You can also try and check using sleep condition after clicking option from dropdown.

Comment: After selecting any option of any select if the page reloads whole DOM is reloaded and every WebElements from previous DOM are lost. You need to redefine required WebElements after each selecting an option.

Comment: After selecting an option, the page doesn't reload. I tried implementing a wait time after clicking the option anyway, it does nothing.